# Is "thanks" appropriate to be polite in this situation?

Tags: word-choice

Question on usage of "thanks":

On past January I was on my vacations in London taking some photos of London Bridge when I made a joke with some foreign photographers (Germans, I think) : I was holding a very common Sony camera, and I said something like that: "let me teach you how to take photos with my professional camera". Everyone laughed and one of them offered to take a panoramic photo of me using my memory card on his camera. I was very pleased, said "Thanks so much!" and left.

My question is:

In this situation, was "thanks" appropriate to politely demonstrate that I was very pleased with what they did?

Comment: PS: If someone with enough reputation could please edit this question and change it into a community wiki, it would be nice to post some tips and advices for people travelling to English-spoken-countries, like "how to behave", "what not to do" etc.

Comment: A question about using *thanks* is appropriate for this site, but not questions about behavior and cultural customs that do not pertain to language.

Comment: I agree with Kosmonaut. I'm making a small edit to your question to remove the part that would make it off-topic. I hope you don't mind... (let me know if you do, I can revert it).

Comment: I imagine non-verbal cues and tones of voice would fill in for any lack of expressiveness in the language.

Comment: Define "*appropriate*".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many phrases that you could have used to thank them. Here are a few of them:

1. "Thank you" / "Thanks" / "Thank you
   very much". These are all polite enough.
2. "Cheers!". More informal, but still polite enough. This would have been valid because you were in the UK. But it doesn't apply to the US, for example.
3. "Thank you very much. That was very kind!"

Based on your description of the situation, I think that #3 would have better expressed to them what you felt.

Comment: "Thanks so much!" is a bit of an Americanism in my experience but not unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds polite to me.  As a native speaker (Canadian English) I probably would have said the same thing.